# Does Spotfire Server do any caching beyond On-Demand data?

Tags: tomcat, caching, spotfire, tibco-topic

I'm performing benchmark testing for a new Spotfire server and while I realize that the web player has caching for multiple accesses of a DXP, I'm not really sure if the desktop client is caching for repeated access. Is that something I should even test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The desktop client opens the dxp locally. Embedded data is opened on the local RAM and information links are from the server. If the client retrieves data as and when it needs it then server performance would impact the client. May I ask what kind of benchmark testing you are doing?